# CPU load on Raspberry Pi Zero launching a python script is always 100%

Tags: python, memory-management, raspberry-pi, cpu-usage

we are running a python script that has a bit of RMS calculation and a TensorFlow model. As soon as I launch the python script the CPU load goes to 100% on a Raspberry Zero W. For the information, memory_load to 50% and disk usage to 45%.

Is there a way to find what resources are exactly taking 100% of the CPU?

Would using a faster uSD help here? (Assuming the CPU is spending lots of time reading from flash memory).

Comment: If your script never sleeps, it will consume as much processor time as it can. The Pi Zero[w] only has one core, so any process that never sleeps will drive the usage up to 100% as there is always something to do. You'd have to show us your script to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Use `top` from the commandlIne? But chances are it will show you Python is taking all your CPU - why is that a surprise?

Comment: Thanks barny, the fact is the same python script takes an average of 25% on a 3B+, which is fair enough as it is a QUAD core. As the python script is running some TF analysis (using the 1.9 version I believe), would it be a system issue that the Raspberry is running 100% of the time for let's say 10 days in a row?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the task manager on your raspberry pi which is located in the main menu under accessories. If it is not there you can just click control - alt - delete. By doing this you can see which programs are running and how much CPU they are using as well as other information. You can try overclocking your Pi to make the CPU faster.

Comment: Actually, we do that check and it is our python script that is taking most of the load.

Comment: So did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing, and had to do a quick search and found this page. On my Raspberry Pi Zero W, without desktop and using one SSH session to show htop and the second to run a simple Python script in the interpreter like this:

```py
while True:
    pass
```

will bring the CPU usage up to 100% until I break the script, so I just assume that's the nature of the beast.